# How to add Unique nos in order email for each unit of woocommerce product sold

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to email the random unique nos for each quantity of product sold

For example : 
A buyer buys 2 products - A & B
A -  4 quantities 
B -  5 quantities

Then the email for the order that the buyer & admin receives should have some 
unique nos (nos will be generated randomly so they can't be predicted)

4 unique nos for A
& 
5 unique nos for B

Same no's will be emailed to both admin & buyer

```
I edited the file  
woocommerce\emails\email-order-items.php

echo "<br>";
for($ri=0;$ri<$item['qty'];$ri++){
echo rand(10000, 90000);
echo',';
}
```

Random no are added but different no s are emailed to both the buyer & admin

So i guess this method won't work .

So please help me some alternative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution if this helpful for you. I think you can store unique nos in database order item meta when product sold. Put this hook in your active  theme functions.php file.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_order_item_meta', 'add_random_number_item_meta', 10, 2 );

function add_random_number_item_meta( $item_id, $item_data ){
  // store each product item quantity in array
  $random = array();
  for( $i = 0; $i < $item_data['quantity']; $i++ )
  $random[$i] = rand(10000, 90000);
  // save unique numbers array each order item
  wc_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, '_unique_nos', $random );   

}
```

After this print unique numbers in email each order item.

```
//woocommerce\emails\email-order-items.php

 $unique_numbers = wc_get_order_item_meta( $item_id,  '_unique_nos', true );
 echo implode( "," , $unique_numbers );

// This will be same both for admin or customer
```

Saved unique numbers in future you can show in admin order dashboard.

Tested: Woocommerce 2.6.x

Comment: You are generating random numbers, how are you guaranteeing that they are unique?

Comment: No i think some time you got same number recently added in your order.
Implement issue about you got different unique nos in email admin or customer.

Comment: I think you can use item id because item id it will be every time unique or you can make combination of different numbers example below.
item_id+product_id+quantity+order_id etc.

Comment: You can also use php function like uniqid. http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php

uniqid( $item_id ); // prefix $item_id

Comment: A lot depends on how unique the numbers need to be and how he/she plans to use it, but I like your plan to add the `order_id` and `product` id.

Comment: What you have any issue ?

Comment: @user5200704 This is a  awesome solution ..... i checked the emails , the no's are same...  as wanted just one issue that because i am using woocommerce product vendor plugin , so i was expecting the same mails will also go to vendors but that's not the case .. i guess i will have to make this same change in some other file of the woocommerce product vendor plugin  too .. any ways thanks a lot